# Angular 9 - Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: angular, angular9

I am getting the following error:

> Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)

when I try to use my AutoLocate function (below) by subscribing to it thusly:

```
this.AutoLocate().subscribe(data => { this.GotLoc = data});
```

Below is the AutoLocate function and also a GetAddress function that I use to get a complete model that uses Lat/Long and Address.

```
  AutoLocate() {
    let AutoLocatedLocation: PlaceLocation;
    if(!Capacitor.isPluginAvailable('Geolocation')) {
      this.Alert.create({header: 'Location Service Error', message: 'Could not initialize Location Services! Please call support!'})
      return;
    }
    Plugins.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(GeoPosition => {
      return this.coordinates = {lat: GeoPosition.coords.latitude, lng: GeoPosition.coords.longitude};
    }).then(coords => {
      this.GetAddress(coords.lat, coords.lng).subscribe(res => {
        this.Address = res;
        return AutoLocatedLocation = { lat: coords.lat, lng: coords.lng, address: res};
      });
    }).catch(error => {
      this.Alert.create({header: 'Location Service Error', message: 'Could not initialize Location Services! Please call support!'})
      console.log("Location: ", error);
    });
  }

  private GetAddress(lat: number, lng: number) {
    return this.http.get<any>(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${lat},${lng}&key=${environment.googleMapsAPIKey}`)
    .pipe(map(geoData => {
      if (!geoData || !geoData.results || geoData.results.length === 0) {
        return null;
      }
      return geoData.results[0].formatted_address;
    }));
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `this.AutoLocate()` doesn't return an observable, hence the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you're mixing Promises with Observables. Moreover the `AutoLocate()` function isn't returning anything at the moment.

You could either convert observable to promise or vice-versa. I'd do the former using RxJS `from` function. Then you could apply the necessary operators to transform the data

```js
import { of, from, NEVER } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

AutoLocate(): Observable<any> {     // <-- return type `Observable`
  let AutoLocatedLocation: PlaceLocation;
  if(!Capacitor.isPluginAvailable('Geolocation')) {
    this.Alert.create({header: 'Location Service Error', message: 'Could not initialize Location Services! Please call support!'})
    return NEVER;       // <-- use RxJS `NEVER` constant - it'll never emit
  }
  
  return from(Plugins.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()).pipe(  // <-- return the observable
    switchMap(GeoPosition => {
      const coords = { lat: GeoPosition.coords.latitude, lng: GeoPosition.coords.longitude };
      this.coordinates = coords;  // <-- why is this needed though?
      return this.GetAddress(coords.lat, coords.lng).pipe(
        map(res => {
          this.Address = res;     // <-- again, is this needed here?
          return ({ ...coords, address: res });  // spread operator `...` retains old values while adding/modifying other values
        })
      )
    }),
    catchError(error => {
      this.Alert.create({header: 'Location Service Error', message: 'Could not initialize Location Services! Please call support!'});
      return of(error);           // <-- `catchError` must return an observable
    })
  );
}
```

**Breakdown:**

1. `from` function to convert the promise to observable
2. `NEVER` constant to not emit to the subscription instead of a plain JS `return;`
3. `map` operator to transform the emission to the required format
4. `switchMap` operator to map from one observable to another
5. `catchError` operator to catch and trigger an alert. Note that `catchError` *must* return an observable. `of` function is used for that function.

Comment: I obviously need to study Observables and Promises - I am still very much a newbie.  Can you post a link or two that I should read to learn better?

Comment: Almost works!  However, I am getting an error: (parameter) coords: {
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
}
Argument of type '(coords: { lat: number; lng: number; }) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: { lat: number; lng: number; }, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.ts(2345)

Comment: There are many resources to be found. Here are my subjective recommendations for RxJS https://www.learnrxjs.io/ and Promises https://web.dev/promises/

Comment: The error most likely means you're missing the parentheses around the object inside the `map` operator. I've edited the `map` operator to make it more clear how the object is returned.

Comment: Speaking of which you don't actually need the `map` operator here. The object transformation could be done inside the `switchMap`. I've edited the answer to remove the `map`. Please see if the change works.

Comment: I may have found the error. I overlooked the `return` statement inside the `switchMap`. I've edited the answer to return the `this.GetAddress()` function from the `switchMap`. The error should be gone now.

Comment: Yes, VSCode also suggested that return statement.  And it works.  Thanx much!  Appreciate it.  Now for some reading. :-)